# Diagonal fade and/or slide

Tags: jquery, css, slide, fade, diagonal

I would like to make a fade and/or slide function that splits up the page, its contents (in blue) and background-image (in white) in two diagonal parts once you click on prev/next. Furthermore one half of the page (in grey) should start fading and/or sliding earlier than the other. The second half will catch up by fading/sliding faster and the content of the new page should appear in both halves at the same time (half a second or so).

Now, I'm not very experienced at web developing yet so I'm not sure if this is even possible. I have tried looking for this kind of functionality on the web but haven't found anything yet. I would greatly appreciate your help!

[image: example layout]

Comment: So this isn't really what you described, but it's the closest I can think of. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/gupqkoey/)

Comment: Thank you very much already, this will help me get started at least!